# how to run existing restassured tests with gatling?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I'm trying to implement gatling performance tests as a part of my project. I have existing test-cases written in RestAssured with Java and maven as a build tool. Can I re-use those and hook with Gatling. I checked the reference https://abstracta.us/blog/performance-testing/tutorial-use-gatling-maven/ - but mostly it tells me to write new tests for Gatling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible atm.

And the blog post you mentioned is definitely not the reference. The reference is the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/) and the [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/).